# rstan packages install from github

Tags: r, github, installation, rstan

i dont know why i have this error.
since i had aleardy set all of the environment variable, rtools, r, rstudio and home path to `D:\DANNY HUANG\Documents` correctly

p.s. i set the installation program's path to D disk since i don't have enough space in OS disk,

---

```r
> install.packages("rstan", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/", dependencies = TRUE)

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rstan_2.21.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 5225165 bytes (5.0 MB)
downloaded 5.0 MB

package ‘rstan’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in C:\Users\DANNY HUANG\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2D2Wbi\downloaded_packages

>example(stan_model, package = "rstan", run.dontrun = TRUE)

Loading required package: StanHeaders
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rstan’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'processx', details:
  call: loadNamespace(name)
  error: there is no package called ‘ps’
```

Comment: *"error: there is no package called ‘ps’"* ... did you try installing the `ps` package?

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the reply, i installed the ps package before, but i don't know why it didn't work.

so i reinstalled all of the r rstan and rstudio and set up all of the environment variable correctly, of course, and the file name R_programming.

and then it finally works, took me a lot of time, but thank you for your advices